# pause flexslider slideshow when playing mp4?

Tags: javascript, css, flexslider, resume, pause

I'm trying to pause flexslider to play an MP4 file then continue on with the slide loop. I thought I'd cracked it by setting the slide time but obviously this neanderthal approach fails when up on server. I've tried to use some of the code solutions here but I'd appreciate expert advice.

Could someone break this down into easy steps please? 
Thanks

I've bashed the movie into playing with this:

```
<ul class="slides">
                    <li>
                      <video id="wrapper" class="prjVideo" poster="/images/movies/xmas17.jpg" preload="auto" controls autoplay >
                        <source  src="images/movies/xmas17.mp4" class="slide" alt="">
                      </video>
```

It's not pretty.

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Show us the context, with an example of your 'previously tried code solutions' please.

Comment: I'm trying to pause flexslider to let a movie play then in-pause... Can anyone help with my crude attempts to code this? Thanks

                               <video id="wrapper" class="prjVideo" poster="/images/movies/xmas17.jpg" preload="auto" controls autoplay >
                            <source  src="images/movies/xmas17.mp4" class="slide" alt="">
                          </video>
<script> 
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('wrapper')[0];

    video.onended = function(e) {
pausePlay: true;
</script>